# Site Warmup with Azure Websites

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis

I'm trying to setup my Azure Website (not webrole) to warm itself up with Application Initialization.

This feature has been added to Azure Websites in Janurary 2016: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/6972595-application-initialization-to-warm-up-specific-pag

I have my applicationInitialization setup like so in my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <applicationInitialization remapManagedRequestsTo="StartUp.html" >
      <add initializationPage="/" />
      <add initializationPage="/pricing" />
    </applicationInitialization>
...
</system.webserver>
```

I've also tried specifying the hostname like so:

```
<add initializationPage="/pricing" hostname="my.host.name.net />
```

This warmup works fine locally, but when I deploy to an Azure Website I don't get StartUp.html to load or my warm up pages hit.

**Question:** How do I warm up my azure website with ApplicationInitialization?

Here's some of the research I've done on this:
http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization
http://ruslany.net/2015/09/how-to-warm-up-azure-web-app-during-deployment-slots-swap/

Comment: Did you restart the web app after deploying it?

Comment: The configuration you have is correct.  Not sure why it's not working in your case.  Maybe you are publishing a different version of your web.config that doesn't have these settings without realizing?  How are you testing to see if your initialization pages are being called?

Comment: I've FTPed into the instances and checked the web.config to verify that the pages are there.  To test I've turned on application logging and watched my Kudo application log stream. I can see other hits to those pages, not just the warm up ones.  One thing is if I restart the web app I will see the warm up html page, but the other pages won't actually get hit to warm up.